# htaccess redirect and alias root folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a folder in webroot called `foo` at `.com/foo/*/`. I'm trying to do a few things. I want the contents of the folder `foo` to be accessible via `.com/bar/*` and `.com/bar/baz/*`. However I also want to redirect traffic from `.com/foo/*` to `.com/bar/*` so that users migrate to the new endpoint. The idea is to not break current users with the app open as well.

I have these rules working when separate, however when using them at the same time I just get a redirect loop. I believe things should be combined more with proper flags but I can't seem to figure out the proper combinations.

```
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ /bar/$1 [R=302,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^bar/baz/(.*)$ bar/$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^bar/(.*)$ foo/$1 [QSA]
```

Edit 1:

`.com/bar/` and `.com/bar/baz/` will internally point correctly to the real directory `foo`.

However '.com/bar`and`.com/bar/baz`will not point correctly to the real directory`foo`. Are the rules fixable or would forcing trailing slash be better?

```
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ /bar/$1 [R=307,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^bar/baz/(.*)$ foo/$1 [NC,END]
RewriteRule ^bar/(.*)$ foo/$1 [NC,END]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Apache 2.4+ then you can use `END`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ /bar/$1 [R=302,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^bar/baz/(.*)$ bar/$1 [NC,END]

RewriteRule ^bar/(.*)$ foo/$1 [NC,END]
```

If you are using old Apache e.g. 2.2 etc then use:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+foo/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ /bar/$1 [R=302,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^bar/baz/(.*)$ bar/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^bar/(.*)$ foo/$1 [NC,L]
```